# Wireless conference systems with more than 8 channels?

Tags: microphone, wireless, system, conference

We have a large hall which is used for conferences and meetings. The participants are usually 5-40 people.  We are looking for a system which can provide us:

- Mics infront of every participant of the conference
- Up to 40 persons
- Gooseneck would be better
- Person can turn on or off the mic by push button
- Mics should be wireless

Which brand has such system ?

I searched some systems which can provide only 8 wireless table top mics (RIVOLABS). That is not good for us, as in our case every person need their own mic infront of them.

Comment: well i think what u need is actually multiples of that kind, judging by the fact that each mic has to have it's pre-amp .. http://www.amazon.com/Pyle-PDWM8300-Professional-Conference-Microphone/dp/B003D2O15W something like this maybe? x (persons you need it ...)

Comment: fracke .  its with 8 mics only :/

Comment: first im not giving an answer, just trying to help, second i don't think there's a 40 Mic installation, You understand my comment? You need 5 of those bundles 5x8 = 40, or if someone else knows a better way..

Answer (score 1):

There is **no single system** that will provide you with that many channels and mics out of the box. The highest count I've seen is 12, and that was analog which I can't recommend due to noise susceptibility.

To get beyond the normal 4 or 8 channels per box, you simply **buy more of the same system**, which leads me to the point:

**Make sure that the system you buy is scalable and supports frequency change for each channel (or for the whole set).**

One such system in the high end is [Shure Microflex Wireless](http://www.shure.com/americas/products/wireless-systems/microflex-wireless-systems#configurations). It is very rugged, noiseless and scalable (up to [40 channels or 80 channels](http://www.shure.com/americas/products/discussion-systems/microflex-wireless-systems/mxwapt8-access-point-tranceiver#details) depending on region).

[image: Microflex Wireless]

Other alternatives:

- Shure [DCS 6000](http://www.shure.com/americas/products/discussion-systems/dcs-6000-digital-conference-system). Up to 3800 mics
- Bosch [CCS 1000 D Digital Discussion System](http://www.boschsecurity.com/). Up to 80 mics
- Gonsin [DCS-3021](http://www.gonsin.com/productinfo.aspx?id=139). Up to 500 mics
- Beyer Dynamic [Quinta](http://europe.beyerdynamic.com/shop/ct/conference-technology/product-line/conference-systems-1/control-unit/quinta-cu.html). Up to 150 mics
- AKG [CS3](http://www.akg.com/pro/p/cs3system). Up to 60 mics

[This article](http://www.installation-international.com/conferencing-equipment-top-10-solutions-to-boost-productivity/) proves additional info on them (and others). These are all expensive high end scalable systems. If you are on a very tight budget, you might check if an analog 8 ch. system like [Pyle PDWM8300](http://www.pyleaudio.com/sku/PDWM8300/Professional-conference-Desktop-VHF-Wireless-Microphone-System) will allow using multiple mics on the same channel (I honestly don't know and wouldn't count on it). Try asking them.

Answer (score -1):

The [Bosch DCN Wireless System](http://iprobesolutions.com/docs/commercial-brochure-en-us-bosch-dcn-wireless.pdf) can handle up to 32 channels. Last year Bosch released an upgrade to DCN Wireless. This new wireless conference system is expected to expand support to at least 32 channels from early 2018. [See the DICENTIS Wireless Conference System.](http://iprobesolutions.com/conference-systems/dicentis-wireless-conference-system)